# system of ODE through NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I am quite puzzled to solve the coupled ode's numerically. 
Please tell me why it runs for a long time and not giving any output in mathematica. I am using NDsolve. please have a look

```
NDSolve[{ x'[t] == x[t]/y[t] + x[t]/z[t] - x[t]/z[t]^2, 
          y'[t] == 1 + y[t]/z[t] - (2 y[t])/z[t]^2, 
          z'[t] == -z[t] - z[t]/y[t] - (2 z[t])/y[t]^2,
          x[0] == 2,
          y[0] == 5, 
          z[0] == 7},
        {x, y, z},
        {t, -10, 10},
        MaxSteps -> Infinity]
```

Comment: Just a suggestion : you can simplify the system with the change of variable `x[t]->Exp[p[t]], z[t]->Exp[q[t]]`. Also, the first equation is actually decoupled so you only need to solve the remaining two.

Answer (score 4):

It seems there is a singularity in t=-4.64095 and t=2.2479405927739124.
You can try:

```
sol = NDSolve[{Derivative[1][x][t] == 
    x[t]/y[t] + x[t]/z[t] - x[t]/z[t]^2, 
       Derivative[1][y][t] == y[t]/z[t] - (2*y[t])/z[t]^2 + 1, 
   Derivative[1][z][t] == -(z[t]/y[t]) - (2*z[t])/y[t]^2 - z[t], 
       x[0] == 2, y[0] == 5, z[0] == 7}, {x, y, z}, {t, -4.62, 2.23}, 
  MaxSteps -> 1000000]

Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol], {t, -4.62, 2.23}, 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: @Soodeh Z. your solution is very interesting. But how you find the singularity in the time point?

Comment: @Enter `NDSolve` finds them for you: try `NDSolve[sys, {x, y, z}, {t, -10, 10}, MaxSteps -> 10000]`