# Numerically solving a system of ODEs with parameters

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions

I am working on solving a system of coupled ordinary differential equations with initial values given. When I searched about my requirements I got the similar answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26225/system-of-ode-through-ndsolve/207918#207918). But I got another condition in my requirements in that I have parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the equations, Like so:

```
α*Derivative[1][x][t] == x[t]/y[t] + x[t]/z[t] - x[t]/z[t]^2, 
β*Derivative[1][y][t] == y[t]/z[t] - (2*y[t])/z[t]^2 + 1,
Derivative[1][z][t] == -(z[t]/y[t]) - (2*z[t])/y[t]^2 - z[t], 
x[0] == 2, y[0] == 5, z[0] == 7}
```

In this case, I have to find the solution for different values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. How do I include $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in my code, so that I can vary them as parameters.

```
sol = 
  NDSolve[
    {Derivative[1][x][t] == x[t]/y[t] + x[t]/z[t] - x[t]/z[t]^2, 
     Derivative[1][y][t] == y[t]/z[t] - (2*y[t])/z[t]^2 + 1,
     Derivative[1][z][t] == -(z[t]/y[t]) - (2*z[t])/y[t]^2 - z[t], 
     x[0] == 2, y[0] == 5, z[0] == 7}, {x, y, z}, {t, -4.62, 2.23}, 
     MaxSteps -> 1000000]

Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol], {t, -4.62, 2.23},
  Frame -> True, Axes -> None]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use [`ParametricNDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html) or 

[`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the parameters in the set of equations and the function `ParametricNDSolve` in place of `NDSolve`.

Here is the first approach where I will hard wire α and β to 1 and 2.

```
sol = NDSolve[
  {
   1*Derivative[1][x][t] == x[t]/y[t] + x[t]/z[t] - x[t]/z[t]^2,
   2*Derivative[1][y][t] == y[t]/z[t] - (2*y[t])/z[t]^2 + 1,
   Derivative[1][z][t] == -(z[t]/y[t]) - (2*z[t])/y[t]^2 - z[t],
   x[0] == 2,
   y[0] == 5,
   z[0] == 7
   },
  {x, y, z},
  {t, -4.62, 2.23},
  MaxSteps -> 1000000
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, my own personal quirk is to define functions using parts of `sol` rather than `Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol` in the `Plot` command.

```
x[t_] = sol[[1, 1, 2]][t];

y[t_] = sol[[1, 2, 2]][t];

z[t_] = sol[[1, 3, 2]][t];
```

Note the use of `Set` rather than `SetDelayed`.

And then

```
Plot[{x[t], y[t], z[t]},
 {t, -4.62, 2.23},
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> None,
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Black}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Rather than hard wiring α and β to 1 and 2 use `ParametricNDSolve` and allow them to be parameters.

```
solP = ParametricNDSolve[
  {
   α*Derivative[1][x][t] == x[t]/y[t] + x[t]/z[t] - x[t]/z[t]^2,
   β*Derivative[1][y][t] == y[t]/z[t] - (2*y[t])/z[t]^2 + 1,
   Derivative[1][z][t] == -(z[t]/y[t]) - (2*z[t])/y[t]^2 - z[t],
   x[0] == 2,
   y[0] == 5,
   z[0] == 7
   },
  {x, y, z},
  {t, -4.62, 2.23},
  {α, β},
  MaxSteps -> 1000000
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now to invoke the function the correct syntax is to use as arguments `[α, β][t]`

Thus we define three parameters function as

```
x[α_, β_, t_] = solP[[1, 2]][α, β][t];

y[α_, β_, t_] = solP[[2, 2]][α, β][t];

z[α_, β_, t_] = solP[[3, 2]][α, β][t];
```

When we make the same plot using α and β equal to 1 and 2 the syntax is:

```
Plot[{x[1, 2, t], y[1, 2, t], z[1, 2, t]},
 {t, -4.62, 2.23},
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> None,
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Black}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and we get identical results as before.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I applied ParametricNDSolve in my case and It worked, but i am not understanding this part
`x[α_, β_, t_] = solP[[1, 2]][α, β][t];

y[α_, β_, t_] = solP[[2, 2]][α, β][t];

z[α_, β_, t_] = solP[[3, 2]][α, β][t];`
What is that [1,2],[2,2],[3,2] represents?

Comment: The double brackets `[[1,2]]` are a shortcut for `Part`. Look in the documentation for `Part`. `solP` is a list of lists. `Part` extracts the parts. Try this experiment. Type in your notebook `solP`, `solP[[1]]`, `solp[[1,1]]` and `solP[[1,2]]`. Repeat for `solP[[2]]` and `solP[[3]]`. This should clarify it.